# How to replace the host variable in a header in nginx

Tags: nginx, http-headers

I am trying to replace the host variable in the header in nginx configuration, such that `some.random.sub.example.net` becomes `net-some.random.sub.example.com`. i have tried the following :

```
if ($host ~* "^([^.]+(\.[^.]+)*)\.example.net$"){

set $sub $1;

set $host1 "http://net-$sub.example.com";

break;

}
```

and then in the location directive, i have:

```
location / {

proxy_set_header    HOST $host1;

some conf

}
```

it dodn't work though !

**EDIT**

full configuration :

```
server {#http

  listen          80 default_server;

  server_name     *.example.com;

  large_client_header_buffers 4 16k;

  access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;

  error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

  if ($host ~* "^([^.]+(\.[^.]+)*)\.example.net$"){

  set $sub $1;

  set $host1 http://cn-$sub.example.com;

  break;

}


  location / {



    proxy_pass          http://ghs.google.com;

    proxy_set_header    HOST $host1;

    proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-Host $host;

    proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-Server $host;

    proxy_set_header    X-Real-IP $remote_addr;

    proxy_set_header    X-Real-HOST  $host;

    proxy_set_header    Proxy-Hostname $scheme://$http_host;

    proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-Proto https;

    proxy_pass_request_headers     on;

    proxy_redirect                off;

    proxy_intercept_errors        on;

    proxy_redirect                false;

  }


}
```

Comment: What exactly didn't work?

Comment: the server passes $host instead of $host1

Comment: Show full nginx config.

Comment: updated in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See http proto -- in `Host` directive you don't pass http/https -- only server name

Answer (score 0):

ok, after a lot of experiments, i solved it.

```
set $host1 http://cn-$sub.example.com;
```

should be :

```
set $host1 cn-$sub.example.com;
```

any explanation ?